# Wondering about limit comparison test and its application

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question about the limit comparison test. In particular if it is valid to use in the question I will post.

I am interested in determining wether the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty ln(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1})$$ is convergent or divergent.

I wanted to be able to use some sort of power expansion that was more familiar to get a sense first of wether the series might converge or diverge.

First off, is it valid to say $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty ln(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1})=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty ln(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2})=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty ln(1-\frac{1}{n^2})$$

Then using the power series it seems to me that it might converge, so I say consider the p series with p=2 and (is this next step valid) consider the $$lim_{n \to \infty}n^2ln(\frac{n^2}{n^2-1})=-lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1-1/n^2}{1/n^2}$$

Letting x=1/n, we would have $$ -lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ln(1-x^2)}{x^2}$$ and after applying l'hospitals rule , $$-lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{1-x^2}=-1$$ which is a finite value (suggesting both converge) but less than zero.

Mainly my question is does the limit comparison test still apply when the limit is less than zero, as long as finite? Could we not just take absolute values at one step or something so that it allowed? Is the rest of the work seem valid?

Thank you all

Comment: You can just consider the series without the negative sign.  Then, your limit will work out to be $1$.  So, the series without the negative sign converges.  Multiplying by $-1$ will not affect the convergence.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 , I see thanks. Is the way I did the limit valid?

Comment: Yes.  It is valid.  You forgot to put $\ln$ on the second limit though.  And, you forgot a negative in the chain rule of your derivative.  So, the answer should be $1$, not $-1$.